# Paste into Excel locked cells

Tags: excel, paste, protected

I'm creating a template for users to input data into.  All I want them to be able to do is copy their data from their source and put it into Cells A21-D21.  Once pasted they cannot delete or alter anything, excel is used only to be able to print.  Repasting is fine as this will be a template.  Ideally, users would export directly into this protected worksheet and be done with it, but instrument software just calls for excel not a specific database location.

In short, users get data from an instrument and it is saved in a format that it cannot be manipulated but neither can it be shown on any computer except what's connected to the instrument.  I need this data to be put into excel but cannot be altered.  Auditors can compare the Raw data to the excel if they choose.

Is there a way to have worksheet protected and select the one unlocked cell(Format Cell), A1, and then have the entire range of A21-D21 filled/pasted into?

The thinking is that people will manipulate the raw data to get the answers they want but this will limit users to paste only.

So I guess, simply, I'm hoping to find a way to allow users to copy/paste and THAT'S IT! ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to do what you want inside Excel, but it can be done programatically.

```
// Note: need to add reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to get these namespaces
// In Visual Studio, choose Project > Add Reference > COM > Type Libraries >
//   Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = @"c:\users\eric.sundquist\desktop\book1.xlsx";
            int worksheetNumber = 1;
            List<string> contents = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4" };

            PasteIntoProtectedSheet(fileName, worksheetNumber, contents);
        }

        static void PasteIntoProtectedSheet(string fileName, int worksheetNumber,
                List<string> contents)
        {
            Application excel = new Application();
            Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileName);

            workbook.Sheets[worksheetNumber].Unprotect(); 
                // Can pass in password as parameter if needed

            Range range = workbook.Sheets[1].Range("A21:D21");

            for (int column = 0; column < contents.Count; column++)
            {
                range.Cells[1, column + 1] = contents[column];
            }

            workbook.Sheets[worksheetNumber].Protect();

            workbook.Save();
            workbook.Close();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
        }
    }
}
```